# How to connect more than one telnet session to Cisco router ( Port Com10 )?

Tags: cisco, router, telnet

I am working on connecting more than one telnet session to Cisco Router. I was unsuccessful till now and decided to post it for getting any valuable directions and info.

Thanks

Comment: You can set a vlan (management vlan) and set a FastEthernet Port for your Telnet sessions to this vlan

Comment: @kockiren: Thank you, will explore and get back to you. Will this link help me http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/sw/iosswrel/ps1831/products_configuration_guide_chapter09186a008034799a.html

Comment: In my answer there is a link to a Tutorial for setting up a Management VLAN

Answer (score 2):

You must define more vty lines:

```
line vty 0 4
```

This results in a maximum of 5 Connections. Read more [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/data-center/configure-lines-and-vtys-on-cisco-routers/)
and for brevity [here](http://www.mcmcse.com/cisco/guides/telnet_passwords_and_privilege_levels.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

If you want wo use a Interface to configure your switch with telnet, ssh or HTTP you should create a Management VLAN, then you can create more than one Telnet/SSH Session to your router/switch.

Maybe this [tutorial](http://www.freeccnaworkbook.com/workbooks/ccna/configuring-a-management-vlan-interface) help you: